# Compare two array with object equity

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop, object

I've two type to data structures

```
   var dataA = [
  {
    "Employee Name": "Mr. X",
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    "Employee Name": "Mr. Y",
    id: "2"
  },
  {
    "Employee Name": "Mr. Z",
    id: "3"
  }
];

var dataB = [
  {
    id: "1",
    "Portfolio Lead": "A"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    "Portfolio Lead": "B"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    "Portfolio Lead": "D"
  }
];
```

Now I'm comparing the `id` value of both the array's and adding the `"Portfolio Lead"` property to `dataA`.

Below is the code,

```
function mergeTwoArray() {
  dataA.forEach(row => {
    dataB.forEach(lead => {
      if (lead["id"] === row["id"]) {
        row["Portfolio Lead"] = lead["Portfolio Lead"];
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(dataA);
}
```

Issue is,

When the `id` did not match, I need to add `"Portfolio Lead"` as `#NA`. If I try to add the if statement all the objects are adding `"Portfolio Lead"` as `#NA`.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

stackBlitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nypqge?file=index.ts

**Output should be**

```
var dataA = [
  {
    "Employee Name": "Mr. X",
    id: "1",
    "Portfolio Lead": "A"
  },
  {
    "Employee Name": "Mr. Y",
    id: "2",
    "Portfolio Lead": "B"
  },
  {
    "Employee Name": "Mr. Z",
    id: "3",
    "Portfolio Lead": "#NA"
  }
];
```

Comment: what do you want in output ? can u plz describe more.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Add a bool condition to check if a match occurred. If it did not, then set your object property to "#NA" as desired.

```
function mergeTwoArray() {
  dataA.forEach(row => {
    var rowMatches = false;
    dataB.forEach(lead => {
      if (lead["id"] === row["id"]) {
        rowMatches = true;
        row["Portfolio Lead"] = lead["Portfolio Lead"];
      }
    });
    if (!rowMatches) {
      row["Portfolio Lead"] = "#NA";
    }
  });
  console.log(dataA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
function mergeTwoArray() {
  dataA.forEach(row => {
    let idxId = dataB.findIndex((lead) => lead["id"] == row["id"]);

    if (idxId >= 0) {
      row["Portfolio Lead"] = dataB[idxId]["Portfolio Lead"];
    } else {
      row["Portfolio Lead"] = "#NA";
    }
  });
  console.log(dataA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an else if statement like as below -

```
else if(row["id"] > lead["id"]){
    row["Portfolio Lead"] = "#NA";
}
```

When you are putting `row["Portfolio Lead"] = "#NA";` in else block its updating everytime as for each iteration in outer loop, inner loop executed the length of *dataB* times. And here I am checking if outer loop's id > inner loop's id then update.

so your code will look like:

```
dataA.forEach(row => {
  dataB.forEach(lead => {
    if (lead["id"] === row["id"]) {
      row["Portfolio Lead"] = lead["Portfolio Lead"];
    } else if(row["id"] > lead["id"]){
      row["Portfolio Lead"] = "#NA";
    }
  });
});
```